# What determines the requirement for a guide when a foreigner wants to drive a vehicle he brought from abroad in China?

Tags: legal, driving, china, driving-licenses

It is well known that a foreigner who wants to drive a foreign vehicle inside China needs to be accompanied by a guide - which makes this very costly: I have been quoted almost 7000 USD for 2 weeks drive through China, which is not something I am willing to pay, so either I find another way, or abandon the idea for the trip.

One travel agent claims to be able to arrange self-driving in China without a guide, but attempts to get in contact with him are unsuccessful: http://www.laurastraveltales.com/overlanding/overlanding-china-self-drive-and-without-a-guide-its-now-possible/

However lets look at these facts:

1) Foreigners can get a Chinese driving licence in China and drive Chinese-registered vehicles inside China without being accompanied by a guide.

2) For the expensive tourist self-drive through China with a guide, one needs to obtain a Chinese driving licence and affix Chinese licence plates for the vehicle anyway.

If the foreigner has a Chinese driving licence and his vehicle has Chinese licence plates, what makes him still need to be accompanied by a guide, while the same foreigner with his Chinese driving licence could borrow a Chinese vehicle and drive it himself without a guide? What makes the vehicle he brought from abroad, which now has Chinese licence plates, any "less Chinese" then a vehicle he could borrow in China and drive without a guide? What caveat in Chinese law requires one to be accompanied by a guide in one situation, but not the other? What I am missing here?

Comment: Questions tagged [rationale] and [legal] are a hard one but my guess is that in the one case the car has to enter and leave China before and after the trip.

Comment: It could be a scam by tourist agencies, rather than a real requirement.

Comment: i was just wondering, how can you bring a foreign vehicle to China ?!

Comment: @JoeBlow: that's what I am trying to find out. Certainly possible with a specialized travel agent and a guide, but trying to figure out how to avoid the compulsory guide which makes this a very expensive endeavor.

Comment: Sure - I just meant, I mean, from what country!?  Surely you mean driving it in to China right?  (ie, not arriving by RoRo or some such ??)

Comment: @JoeBlow yes, for example driving from Kyrgyzstan via the Irkeshtam border crossing, and then to exit China to Laos via Mohan Port crossing.

Comment: I see.  Sounds like an amazing trip, enjoy!

Comment: Related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14610/is-it-possible-for-a-foreigner-to-drive-through-mainland-china-in-a-foreign-re

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unable to quote any laws or regulation here, but take a closer look at it, in the end the cases are different:

**License**
As I wrote in [my answer to your related question here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/78835/32134), in case 2) you only get *some sort of temporary driving licenses*. Whereas in case 1) you will [need a full-blown Chinese driving license](http://wikitravel.org/en/Driving_in_China), international licenses are not accepted.

**Car Registration**
Again, in case 1) there is nothing special about the car, but in case 2) you are temporarily importing a foreign car and in just about any place in the world there is paperwork etc. associated with that.

So I see it from the point of view that scenario 2) is a fairly special case for the authorities since you do not have a Chinese license and import a car. Instead of saying *no* they do allow this, but under the special conditions of a needed tour company + guide.

Comment: In case the downvote was more than a revenge-dv please do let me know so that I can improve this answer.

Comment: What I don't understand is how for example people in north Vietnam would visit their friends across the border or go shopping in China? It would be bizarre for them to hire a tour company and guide. In all the rest of the world (except North Korea and Myanmar) such things as cross-border car trips are common and normal thing to do, facilitating commerce and allowing people living close to each other, but separated by a border to maintain connections. Does such things simply do not exist across the Chinese border, with own vehicles of residents of neighbouring countries?